# System-settings not opening in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-settings

System-settings in Ubuntu 20.04 is not working. Moreover snap store is not opening too.When I type gnome-control-center,I get the following output:

gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What is the libjpeg.so.8? Installed libjpeg-dev. But the problem remains. Please help.

Comment: "Feezes at the BIOS logo" and "fails to boot" imply crippling hardware problems unrelated to Ubuntu. Rule those out first. Look up how to test your RAM and SMART-test your HDD/SSD.

Comment: And what about the system-settings. On clicking it nothing happens.

Comment: The apt repository for Synpatic (universe) is installed. the synaptic is also installed as per the apt install command, but its not showing in the menu. Magic! A lot of worst changes have happened to the system after the update.